# Do Azure Functions require permissions to publish messages to a Service Bus topic?

Tags: c#, azure-functions, azureservicebus, azure-servicebus-topics

I have an Service Bus Topic Trigger Azure Function(v3) that needs to publish messages to a Service Bus topic. The Service Bus and Azure Function are in the same subscription and resource group.

Do I need to grant any permissions to the Azure Function to allow it to publish messages to the Service Bus topic?

I have already configured the Service Bus connection string in my Azure Function, but when I try to publish messages to the topic it is not publishing and also not throwing any error.

I am using following code to publish message into Service Bus Topic:

```
internal class AzureServiceBus : IMessageBus
    {
        #region private fields
        private const string ContentType = "application/json";
        private readonly ServiceBusSender _serviceBusSender;
        #endregion

        #region ctors
        internal AzureServiceBus(ServiceBusSender serviceBusSender)
        {
            this._serviceBusSender = serviceBusSender;
        }
        #endregion

        #region public methods
        /// <summary>
        /// Publish message into Service Bus Topic 
        /// </summary>
        /// <typeparam name="T"></typeparam>
        /// <param name="message"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public async Task PublishMessageAsync<T>(T message, string messageId)
        {
            var serviceBusMessage = new ServiceBusMessage(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(message.AsJson()))
            {
                ContentType = ContentType
            };
            serviceBusMessage.MessageId = messageId;
            await this._serviceBusSender.SendMessageAsync(serviceBusMessage);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Publish message into Service Bus Topic 
        /// </summary>
        /// <typeparam name="T"></typeparam>
        /// <param name="message"></param>
        /// <param name="messageId"></param>
        /// <param name="filterPropertyName"></param>
        /// <param name="filterPropertyValue"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public async Task PublishMessageAsync<T>(T message, string messageId, string filterPropertyName, string filterPropertyValue)
        {
            try
            {
                var serviceBusMessage = new ServiceBusMessage(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(message.AsJson()))
                {
                    ContentType = ContentType
                };
                serviceBusMessage.MessageId = messageId;
                serviceBusMessage.ApplicationProperties.Add(filterPropertyName, filterPropertyValue);
                serviceBusMessage.CorrelationId = filterPropertyValue;

                await this._serviceBusSender.SendMessageAsync(serviceBusMessage);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex?.StackTrace);
                throw;
            }
        }

        public async Task<bool> PublishMessageReturnTrueAsync<T>(T message, string messageId, string filterPropertyName, string filterPropertyValue)
        {
            try
            {
                var serviceBusMessage = new ServiceBusMessage(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(message.AsJson()))
                {
                    ContentType = ContentType
                };
                serviceBusMessage.MessageId = messageId;
                serviceBusMessage.ApplicationProperties.Add(filterPropertyName, filterPropertyValue);
                serviceBusMessage.CorrelationId = filterPropertyValue;

                await this._serviceBusSender.SendMessageAsync(serviceBusMessage);
                
                return true;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex?.StackTrace);
                return false;
            }
        }
        #endregion

        #region internal methods
        internal static IMessageBus Create(ServiceBusSender sender)
        {
            return new AzureServiceBus(sender);
        }
        #endregion

    }
```

Azure Serivce Bus Factory:

```
 public class AzureServiceBusFactory : IMessageBusFactory
    {
        #region private fields
        private readonly ILogger<AzureServiceBusFactory> _logger;
        private readonly ServiceBusConfigOption _serviceBusConfigOption;
        private readonly object _lockObject = new object();
        private readonly ConcurrentDictionary<string, ServiceBusClient> _clients = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, ServiceBusClient>();
        private readonly ConcurrentDictionary<string, ServiceBusSender> _senders = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, ServiceBusSender>();

        #endregion

        public AzureServiceBusFactory(ILogger<AzureServiceBusFactory> logger,
            IOptions<ServiceBusConfigOption> serviceBusConfigOption)
        {
            _logger = logger;
            _serviceBusConfigOption = serviceBusConfigOption.Value;
        }

        #region public methods
        /// <summary>
        /// Get ServiceBusClient
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="senderName"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public IMessageBus GetClient(string senderName)
        {
            _logger.LogInformation("{class} -> {method} -> Start",
                 nameof(AzureServiceBusFactory), nameof(AzureServiceBusFactory.GetClient));

            var connectionString = _serviceBusConfigOption.ConnectionString;

            var key = $"{connectionString}-{senderName}";

            if (this._senders.ContainsKey(key) && !this._senders[key].IsClosed)
            {
                _logger.LogInformation("{class} -> {method} -> End",
                       nameof(AzureServiceBusFactory), nameof(AzureServiceBusFactory.GetClient));

                return AzureServiceBus.Create(this._senders[key]);
            }

            var client = this.GetServiceBusClient(connectionString);

            lock (this._lockObject)
            {
                if (this._senders.ContainsKey(key) && this._senders[key].IsClosed)
                {
                    if (this._senders[key].IsClosed)
                    {
                        this._senders[key].DisposeAsync().GetAwaiter().GetResult();
                    }

                    _logger.LogInformation("{class} -> {method} -> End",
                        nameof(AzureServiceBusFactory), nameof(AzureServiceBusFactory.GetClient));

                    return AzureServiceBus.Create(this._senders[key]);
                }

                var sender = client.CreateSender(senderName);

                this._senders[key] = sender;

                _logger.LogInformation($"ServiceBusClient created connection string:{connectionString}.");
            }

            _logger.LogInformation("{class} -> {method} -> End",
                nameof(AzureServiceBusFactory), nameof(AzureServiceBusFactory.GetClient));

            return AzureServiceBus.Create(this._senders[key]);
        }
        #endregion

        #region protected methods
        /// <summary>
        /// Create ServiceBusClient
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="connectionString"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        protected virtual ServiceBusClient GetServiceBusClient(string connectionString)
        {
            var key = $"{connectionString}";

            lock (this._lockObject)
            {
                if (this.ClientDoesnotExistOrIsClosed(connectionString))
                {
                    try
                    {
                        var client = new ServiceBusClient(connectionString, new ServiceBusClientOptions
                        {
                            TransportType = ServiceBusTransportType.AmqpTcp
                        });

                        this._clients[key] = client;
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        _logger.LogError(ex, $"Failed to create ServiceBusClient, {ex.Message}");
                        throw;
                    }
                }

                return this._clients[key];
            }
        }
        #endregion

        #region private methods
        /// <summary>
        /// Check ClientDoesnotExistOrIsClosed
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="connectionString"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        private bool ClientDoesnotExistOrIsClosed(string connectionString)
        {
            return !this._clients.ContainsKey(connectionString) || this._clients[connectionString].IsClosed;
        }
        #endregion

    }
```

Comment: You need connection string of service bus,thats quite enough

Comment: @RithwikBojja Yes, That's correct, I was facing this issue because I had enabled duplicate detection while creating the topic. As a result, my Azure Function was attempting to push the message into the same Service Bus Topic for further processing, which caused the problem. Once I removed the duplicate detection check, it started working fine.

Answer (score 1):

I have the Simple .NET 6 Azure Function that consumes the messages from the Service Bus Topic that receives the messages from the Logic Apps I have configured:

**Logic App for sending the messages to Service Bus Topic**:

[image]

**Function code**:

```cs
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

namespace KrishSBNet6FunctionApp
{
    public class Function1
    {
        private readonly ILogger<Function1> _logger;
        public Function1(ILogger<Function1> log)
        {
            _logger = log; 
        }
        [FunctionName("Function1")]
        public void Run([ServiceBusTrigger("messagetopic", "topicsubsn", Connection = "SBConnection")] string mySbMsg, ILogger _logger)
        {
            _logger.LogInformation($"C# ServiceBus topic trigger function processed message: {mySbMsg}");
        }
    }
}
```

**Note**:

1. **`SBConnection`** is the Service Bus Connection String defined in the `local.settings.json` file if running locally and if running in the Azure Cloud, that connection string should be added to Function App Configuration > Application Settings in the portal.
2. **SAS Policy** from the Service Bus Namespace should have the right access to send, receive and manage the messages:
   [image]
3. Source Code is the default code generated by VS 2022 IDE or can take from below MS Doc and modify the things like Connection Name, Connection String, Topic Name, Subscription name according to your requirement.

**Result**:

[image]

**Coming to Access Management**:

I have Generic Role i.e., Contributor to all of the resources/Services in Azure so I can be able to send/receive the messages from the Service Bus Resource.

As per this [MS Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-service-bus-trigger?tabs=in-process,extensionv5&pivots=programming-language-csharp#grant-permission-to-the-identity) of Azure SB Access Management, ASB Data Receiver and Data Owner roles to be assigned for the Trigger type and ASB data Sender for the Output Binding.

> For triggering from Service Bus topics, the role assignment needs to have effective scope over the Service Bus subscription resource. If only the topic is included, an error will occur. Some clients, such as the Azure portal, don't expose the Service Bus subscription resource as a scope for role assignment. In such cases, the Azure CLI may be used instead.

Comment: Thanks for the prompt response! Actually, I was facing this issue because I had enabled duplicate detection while creating the topic. As a result, my Azure Function was attempting to push the message into the same Service Bus Topic for further processing, which caused the problem. Once I removed the duplicate detection check, it started working fine.